# Automatically add tasks to list Task from another list

Tags: development, list

I have 4 lists:

[image: Attribute List]
[image: Task List]
[image]

and Project Tasks which contains Items (content type:Summary Task).
When I add new Item in Project Tasks I need to add all Tasks (content type:Task) from my list TaskAttributeList automatically.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

I will strongly recommend you to use event receivers and not workflows unless there is a business process involved.

Event receivers are more reliable, and will happen instant while workflows might have a delay.

You did not specify what versions of SharePoint you are using, but I am guessing 2010 from your screenshots.

These might help get you started:

[Event Receiver for List Instance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff398052%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)
[Create an Event Receiver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff398052%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using Event Receiver or workflow. I would suggest Event Receiver.